# Dynamic variable behavior in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

I created code below, but works only for PHP 7+ version.

What I need to change here to make `$$variablename[$key]` work on 5.6 version?

[Online PHP test](https://3v4l.org/qk5ZL)

```php
$g_module_id_bar_1['id'] = 5;

$i = 1;

$variablename = 'g_module_id_bar_'.$i;
$key = 'id';

echo $$variablename[$key];  // doesn't work
```

Result should be: **5**

Comment: `echo ${$variablename}[$key];` Someone else can turn that into a proper answer with reference links to why curly braces work in this situation ;)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092299/variable-variables-handling-order-changes-in-php-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5, you should write

`echo ${$variablename}[$key];`

The reason why the code in your question works in PHP 7 is that PHP 7 introduced changes in how it handles indirect variables:

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order, as opposed to the previous mix of special cases. The table below shows how the order of evaluation has changed.

More specifically, the following expression:
`$$foo['bar']['baz']`

Was interpreted in PHP 5 as:
`${$foo['bar']['baz']}`

And in PHP 7:
`($$foo)['bar']['baz']`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect